# Sort multidimensional vectors without null values

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

```
vector<vector<int>> sort_arr;
int n = 4, k = 2;

sort_arrsort_arr.resize(n);
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i){
sort_arrsort_arr[i].resize(k);
}

int sum = 16;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ;  j++){
    sort_arrsort_arr[i][j] = sum;
    sum--;
    }
}

sort(  sort_arrsort_arr.begin(), sort_arrsort_arr.end());
```

Since the vector is 4x2 and i've only put values in the first 2 rows, when i sort the vector i get the first 2 rows as 0,0 and 0,0 How do i ignore these values while sorting ?

Comment: What do mean by "ignore these values while sorting"? They must go somewhere in the result. Do you mean to sort them to the end? Or do you mean sort only the populated portion of the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to sort the portion you have filled, use

```
sort(sort_arrsort_arr.begin(), sort_arrsort_arr.begin()+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little bit more specific in that what you want to achieve ? you can provide your own comparison operator when sorting

```
 template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp );
```

For more info read the manual
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 0):

Well they're not null values. They are 0, which is a perfectly valid number to sort. If you only want 2 rows, only add two rows. Just do `int n = 2` instead of `4`.

With the information you've given though, you could of course do:

```
sort(sort_arr.begin(), std::next(sort_arr.begin(),2));
```

This will only sort the first two rows.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` in C++ is never `NULL`. If you do the following:

```
int val = (int)NULL;
```

The value of `val` is `0`, which is indistinguishable from any other `int` whose value is `0`. If you really will have those `NULL` "holes" in your multidimensional vector that you want to be ignored I suggest using a `Nullable<int>`.